# validating element cardinality in xml with xsd

Tags: xml, validation, sequence

my XML text looked like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <create>a</create>
    <create>b</create>
    <createname>c</createname>
    <createname>d</createname>
    <primary>k</primary>
    <column>e</column>
    <column>f</column>
</root>
```

Generally,element"create","createname","column" can appear at least once(1 to unbounded),element"primary"  should appear exactly once,all those elements can be in any order.

"xsd:all" allowed just 0 or once;
"xsd:sequece" means elements must show up by order,

How can I use xsd to achieve this validation?

Comment: I think that when you say "prefix", you mean "element".

Answer (score 0):

In short you can't. XML Schema relies on order to enforce the count of elements (except with "all"). Also most "marshaling" libraries require an order. If you have no control of the XML file, one suggestion is to transform it with XSL before validating it.

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="root"></xsl:element>
    <xsl:for-each select="create">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="createname">
        <xsl:for-each select="createname"></xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Mostly try to get rid of this: "all those elements can be in any order"